# Files are not being written in program on repl.it

Tags: python-3.x, replit

I'm writing a bot that gets some data from a webpage and updates a file based on some website data. Here is the relevant code regarding writing the file:

```
file = open("file.txt", 'w')
lines[5] = xxxxx
file.write('\n'.join(lines))
file.close()
```

The whole program runs smoothly without errors when I run it on Python shell. However when I upload it to repl.it (along with .env, requirements.txt, etc.), the file does not get edited. Everything else in my program works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I removed the file extension (renamed "file.txt" to "file") and it works now